# Create multiple tree-DIVs using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

This Shiny code isn't showing the correct output I want:

Shiny Code

```
tags$div(class="block__body", 
  tags$div(class="block__body--one"), 
  tags$div(class="block__body--two"), 
  tags$div(class="block__body--three")
)
```

The current output:

```
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="block__body--one"></div>
  <div class="block__body--two"></div>
  <div class="block__body--three"></div>
</div>
```

The output I want:

```
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="block__body--one">
    <div class="block__body--two">
      <div class="block__body--three">
        hey world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```R
tags$div(class="block__body", 
  tags$div(class="block__body--one", 
    tags$div(class="block__body--two", 
      tags$div(class="block__body--three", "hey world")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I actually got it working within the next few minutes of posting this and forgot to update. Thank you once again though for your help.